# dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) is not getting called even after setting setAcceptDrop(true) in Phonon::VideoWidget

Tags: qt, phonon

I have added `phonon::VideoWidget` in `QGraphicsScene/View` and have set the `setAcceptDrop(true)` for `phonon::VideoWidget`.
I have created a class which is inherited from `QGraphicsView` and have overridden below events function:

```
virtual void dropEvent ( QDropEvent * event );
virtual void dragEnterEvent ( QDragEnterEvent * event);
virtual void mouseMoveEvent ( QMouseEvent * event);
virtual void mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * event);
virtual void dragLeaveEvent ( QDragLeaveEvent * event );
virtual void dragMoveEvent ( QDragMoveEvent * event );
```

Also set `setAcceptDrop(true)` in this class too.

I am receiving all events(mentioned above) except `dropEvent(QDropEvent * event)`. `dropEvent (QDropEvent *)` is getting called if I am adding any other `QGraphicsItem` instead of `Phonon::VideoWidget`.

I'm using Qt 4.8.4 under Windows 7.

Comment: Which phonon version are you using, the one from Qt or KDE?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. im using phonon 4 of QT .

Answer (score 1):

You may need to override `void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent*)` and call `QDragEnterEvent::acceptProposedAction()` to indicate that the widget can handle that drop event.